# Can the opacity of a jqplot tooltip be altered?

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqplot bar chart for which I have implemented the tooltipContentHandler to show an image rather than text. Here is the code...

```
tooltipContentEditor: function(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, jqPlot) {
    var currentItem = myData[0][pointIndex];
    var pid = currentItem[0];
    // Get the image url from static list...
    var pidImage = pidImages[pid];

    var s = "<img src='" +pidImage+ "' width=50px height=50px/>";
    return s;
 }
```

That works fine - the image is displayed when the mouse is moved over a bar. My issue is with the opacity of the image - because part of the image overlays the bar and the other part does not, the image opacity looks odd.

So I though I'd just change the opacity by adding this to the tooltipContentHandler function...

```
$('.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip').css("background", "rgba(208,208,208,1.0)");
```

that made no difference, so I made changes directly in the jqplot css (including the ".min" version):

```
.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip, .jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip {
    /*replace this
      background: rgba(208,208,208,0.5);
     with...*/
    background: rgba(208,208,208,1.0);
}
```

but still the same opacity issue. I then tried making the same rgba change to .jqplot-cursor-tooltip in the css, although I knew that would make no difference.

Anyone got any good ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: you can override the CSS property of the tooltip div for your graph. there you can specify your opacity

Comment: @Gyandeep Is that not exactly what I did above?

Answer (score 1):

I first thought it was an opacity issue as well, but it is an z-index issue as well. So in my case I solved it in CSS with:

```
.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip, .jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip {
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(208,208,208,1)!IMPORTANT;
}
```

The point label has z-index: 2, but the tooltip will end up on top with the same z-index since the tooltip is added afterwards with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

use the `CSS` property:

```
opacity:0.4;
```

on the image to change the opacity.
[CSS Image Opacity help](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I already tried that, although with an opacity of 1.0: `var s = "<img src='" +pidImage+ "' width=50px height=50px style='opacity:1.0'/>";` but it made no difference.

Comment: which browser r u using?

Comment: Chrome (31.0.1650.57)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the

```
.jqplot-cursor-tooltip
```

class instead of the highlighter one or overriding that (using "!important" at the end of the rule)

Here you can find the css rules list: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotCssStyling-txt.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed **opacity for jqPlot tooltip** with:

```
$('.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip').css({'background': '#fafafa', 'padding': '2px 5px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used as 'Anton Danilchenko' told, but inside the Extender method from PieChartModel class, and it worked for me.

pieModel.setExtender(" function(){ $('.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip').css({'background': '#fafafa', 'padding': '2px 5px'}); } ");